# SSRS External Assembly: SecurityPermission in Preview Pane?

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, reporting-services, cas

ok.. spent 3 days with this, learned a lot about this issue, but still can't quite get around it.

I have a SSRS Report, that references **external assembly which connects to sql server**, and while previewing this report in Visual Studio, i get the following exception:

> **SecurityException: Request for the permission of type SqlClientPermission failed**

so, i added this code:

```
new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted).Assert();
```

but this in turn causes this exception:

> **SecurityException: Request for permission of type SecurityPermission failed**
>
> **The zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer**

**from what i've read, this problem should not occur in visual studio preview pane, because  code should run in full trust?**

Never the less, i went ahead and [followed all of the instructions here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842419), in order to give my assembly full trust. I tried adding it by URL, and by Strong Name.

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup"
   version="1"
   PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
   Name="MyNewCodeGroup">
   <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition"
      version="1"
      Url="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\MyAssembly.dll"/>
</CodeGroup>
```

I also saw [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2005/06/16/429795.aspx), and tried putting my code group in the place suggested there.

Furthermore, i tried signing my assembly, and adding a CodeGroup based on strong name (also in My_Computer_Zone.

I also tried using caspol.exe with:

```
caspol -af myassembly.dll
```

So, i think myassembly runs in full trust (although not 100% sure). **I can't figure out why, i still get these permission errors from Visual Studio Preview pane**.

What exactly is needed for my code to be able to Assert that sql permission?

**UPDATE**

i set up a local instance of SSRS server. i can deploy my report there, and it works (since i already added full trust for it), but it STILL won't work in VS. This is a temporary work around, but it sucks for development because it takes long to deploy and eats up a ton of ram..

Comment: Have you tried using the ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain per [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mosharaf/archive/2005/12/20/localreportcustomcode.aspx)?

Comment: where can i set this? remember i am not using any external code to launch the report. just previewing it in visual studio. so all there is is the .rdl file, and the c# method that is called from my code behind

Comment: I don't know of my own knowledge, but per that link, you can embed code in the report by adding "custom code":
_On the Report menu, click Report Properties. 
On the Code tab, in Custom code, type the code._

Comment: Well worded question - I have the exact same issue and am currently looking at it - will keep you posted if I come across a solution. Lemme know if in the mean time you have resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

I had to make two changes in RsPreviewPolicy.config (on the development machine):

```
<CodeGroup
        class="UnionCodeGroup"
        version="1"
        PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
        Name="Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions"
        Description="This code group grants default permissions for code in report expressions and Code element. ">
</CodeGroup>
<CodeGroup
        class="FirstMatchCodeGroup"
        version="1"
        PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
        Description="This code group grants MyComputer code Execution permission. ">
  <IMembershipCondition
      class="ZoneMembershipCondition"
      version="1"
      Zone="MyComputer" />
</CodeGroup>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks @femseks, I just had to change the first code group named "Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions" to "FullTrust" and I was able to use the preview in the report designer.
In my case, the RsPreviewPolicy.config file is under the new location for VS2019, that is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS

Comment: In the server I had to do the same change on file: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\rssrvpolicy.config"

Answer (score 1):

Sonic,

This fixed it for me but I'm guessing that your issue may be down to something else

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\RSPreviewPolicy.config

[or alternatively
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\RSPreviewPolicy.config]

```
                        <CodeGroup
                            class="FirstMatchCodeGroup"
                            version="1"
                            PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
                            Name="  my CustomAssemblyCodeGroup"
                            Description="A special code group for my Report custom assembly.">
                            <IMembershipCondition
                            class="UrlMembershipCondition"
                            version="1"
                            Url="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\my.ReportUtils.dll"/>
                        </CodeGroup>
```

The url value was initially set to the wrong folder

Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.SQLSERVER2012\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\my.ReportUtils.resources.dll"/>

instead of the folder that contains the RSPreviewPolicy.config file and dlls

Even though the same dlls were in both locations it would not work

Silly on my behalf really

Liam